# Why do id and runId change every start of a streaming query?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Every streaming query in Structured Streaming is associated with `id` and `runId`.

[image]

Why do they change when I `stop` and `start` the following query?

```scala
// Reading datasets with records from a Kafka topic
val idsPerBatch = spark.
  readStream.
  format("kafka").
  option("subscribe", "topic1").
  option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").
  load.
  withColumn("tokens", split('value, ",")).
  withColumn("seconds", 'tokens(0) cast "long").
  withColumn("event_time", to_timestamp(from_unixtime('seconds))). // <-- Event time has to be a timestamp
  withColumn("id", 'tokens(1)).
  withColumn("batch", 'tokens(2) cast "int").
  withWatermark(eventTime = "event_time", delayThreshold = "10 seconds"). // <-- define watermark (before groupBy!)
  groupBy($"event_time"). // <-- use event_time for grouping
  agg(collect_list("batch") as "batches", collect_list("id") as "ids").
  withColumn("event_time", to_timestamp($"event_time")) // <-- convert to human-readable date

// start the query and display results to console
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.{OutputMode, Trigger}
val sq = idsPerBatch.
  writeStream.
  format("console").
  option("truncate", false).
  trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(5.seconds)).
  outputMode(OutputMode.Append). // <-- Append output mode
  start
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` is persistent across runs as part of checkpoint metadata.

Since you're using `ConsoleSink` (i.e. `console` output), which [doesn't support checkpointing](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21667) and not providing a checkpoint location, the `id` cannot be fetched from the metadata file (emphasis mine):

> Returns the unique id of this query that persists across restarts
>   **from checkpoint data**.  That is, this id is generated when a query is
>   started for the first time, and will be the same every time it is
>   restarted from checkpoint data

On the other hand, `runId` is generated each time you restart the query:

> Returns the unique id of this run of the query. That is, every start/restart of a query will generated a unique `runId`. Therefore, every time a query is restarted from checkpoint, **it will have the same id but different `runIds`**.